# Flutter detect mobile rotation amount

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to build a camera and I want the application to detect if the mobile is derived a bit or not straight so the image can be clear, is there any Class that I can use to listen for the mobile rotation amount

Answer (score 0):

After a quick search I found [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/sensors_plus). Does the `GyroscopeEvent` class solve your problem? The package provides a stream which you can listen to and which gives you the rotation coordinates.

I haven't used this package before and I'm therefore unable to provide any examples.

Hope I could help ;)